# How to undo kernel settings?

Tags: linux, kernel, sysctl

While trying to read some kernel parameters, I think I have mistakenly set some instead:

```
# sysctl --system -r ^net.*tcp
* Applying /usr/lib/sysctl.d/00-system.conf ...
* Applying /usr/lib/sysctl.d/50-default.conf ...
kernel.sysrq = 16
kernel.core_uses_pid = 1
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 1
net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_source_route = 0
fs.protected_hardlinks = 1
fs.protected_symlinks = 1
* Applying /etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf ...
* Applying /etc/sysctl.conf ...
```

Now, is there a way to undo those changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During a boot *sysctl* settings are initially set to default values hardcoded into the kernel. You most likely don't want to revert to these, as system specific settings are loaded from the various system configuration files by a *sysctl* init script, in a manner similar to the command you executed, except not limited to settings matching a certain pattern.

Unless you've actually edited some settings in any of the configuration files, or configured certain *sysctl* settings directly via [`sysctl`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sysctl.2.html), chances are that you've not actually changed any of the settings by reloading the configuration. If you've actually set some settings directly with `sysctl`, without recording the corresponding change to a particular configuration file, the change will be lost at reboot.

The command `sysctl -a` displays all available *sysctl* values.